# Importing Image folder from NAS

Tags: reactjs

I'm using create-react-app, and building a local to my own network only React page. I can import images using

"import image1 from "./images/DSC00014.jpg";"  and then referencing image1 for a singular image.
I have a nas set up on my raspberry pi, that I can access from windows using //pivault
I have a folder in my Seagate labeled 'images', but I am not sure how to import those images, one or the whole folder. using "//pivault/Seagate/images/DSC00014.jpg" doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the `import image from "<location>"` behaviour in CRA is [intended for *static* resources](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) - as in, they can be explicitly addressed individually *at compile time*

That's fine for logos, icons, page decorations etc, but your page needs to iterate over the resources it finds in a certain location *at run time*. That's a different use-case, and `import` is not suitable here.

You need to remember that even in a "running on localhost" situation, the React code you write will execute *in a browser* so a path like `//pivault/Seagate/images/DSC00014.jpg` doesn't make sense. What you'll need to do is have a HTTP backend of some sort that can:

- return a list of all of the image files in a given directory when queried
- return an actual image when requested for a single filename

It may be that the existing software running on your Raspberry Pi can already do this - in which case you just need to make your React app make the necessary backend calls:

- get the list of all the images
- iterate over them, requesting each image file
- render the list to the page

Comment: makes sense, my seemingly simple project is growing complexity exponentially.